# Angular SPA can't change nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build an angular SPA with angular-ui-router that searches artists from [The Spotify Api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/)
After an artist search and binding artists images and names from all results on my home.html I need to be able to click on an image and change my view from /home to /{{artist.name}}, but when I click on the images my browser doesn't change the view

*app.js:*

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })

.state('chosenArtist', {
    templateUrl: 'views/chosenartist.html',
    controller: 'ChosenartistCtrl',
    param: {pickedArtist: null},
    url: '/artist/{artist.name}'
});
```

home.html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
<ul>
  <li>{{artist.name}}</li>
  <a ng-href="#/artist/{artist.name}"><img class="artist-album-picture" ng-src="{{artist.images[0].url}}" alt=""></a>
</ul>
```

if anyone has some insight on what i could be missing... thanks!

Comment: which angular version are you using? there were some breaking changes made to the router in 1.6, which your code would definitely be affected by.

Comment: @Claies on my bower.json file says "angular": "^1.4.0",

Comment: which means "1.4.0 **or newer.**".   Or more specifically, anything higher than a particular version in the same major range (in this case, 1 is the major, 4 is the minor, but 6 is another minor that can be included). what **actual** version is included in the project?

Comment: Right, I'm using AngularJS v1.6.5

Comment: which means that the duplicate applies to your code.

Comment: Also get familiar with href directive built into ui-router instead of using `ng-href`

Comment: @Claies The link you replied with helped me! thanks <3<3<3